# Clearing the "Network" tab in IE11 developer tools

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-11

How does one clear out the traced HTTP requests from the IE11 "Network" developer tool? There are some icons with little red "X" glyphs at the top but those do something other than clearing the view. It's possible of course with Firefox and Chrome tools, but nothing I've tried works with IE11.

I vaguely recall that IE9 had a "Clear" button but I could be imagining that.

Answer (score 7):

When on the network tab, the option to clear the activity is called 'Clear session' and is located between 'Clear entries on navigate' and 'Content type'.  The icon is a little red x in the upper left corner, and then 3 lines.  It is the one highlighted yellow in the screenshot.[image: screenshot from 11.407.17134.0]